# How display an alert when meters of a longitude change?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an item that displays user's longitude i.e **31.1234567**. I need to display a message that says **Meters differ** whenever the meters change.
I assumed that the third number after the decimal point represents meters - in this case, it's **3**. The code snippet compares the third number of the longitude with the value of the **meter** item. If they differ it displays the message and assign the new third number of longitude to the **meter** item and so on.
When tested, I noticed that the third number never changes even when I walk up to 10 meters with my phone on me. Just the 2 or three numbers on the right side - in this case, **567**.
Second problem, the number of digits before the decimal point - in this case, **2** for the **31**, but longitudes could have 1, 2 or 3 digits in any other part of the world than my part. So, I am not sure if **substr()** method is the solution here.

```js
var vCurrentMeter;
function getVal(item) {
  return document.getElementById(item).innerHTML;
}
function setVal(item, val) {
  document.getElementById(item).innerHTML = val;
}

navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function (position) {
  setVal("currentLong", position.coords.longitude);
  vCurrentMeter = getVal("currentLong").toString().substr(5, 1);
  if (vCurrentMeter !== getVal("previousMeter")) {
    alert("Meters differ");
    setVal("previousMeter", vCurrentMeter);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="currentLong"></input>
<label for="currentLong">Current Longitude:</label>
<br>
<input type="text" id="previousMeter"></input>
<label for="previousMeter">Previous Meter:</label>
```

Comment: You might want to research more about how longitude actually works.

Comment: basically, longitude goes from -180 to +180 ... so, yeah, the digits before the decimal can be 1 2 or 3 .... also, walking 10 metres will change latitude by a varying amount, depending on your latitude, and the direction you are walking - i.e. if you walk 10 metres ... or 10,000 metres north or south, your longitude won't change ... basically, your code isn't close to doing anything useful anywhere on the globe :p

Comment: Your estimate of 1 degree of longitude = 1 kilometer is only right if you're about 50 kilometers from either the north or south pole. You might want to rethink the way you convert coordinate differences into distances.

Comment: This answer may also help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8674/138778

Comment: @JaromandaX Do you mean that I need to use Latitude instead of Longitude to calculate meters one walks?

Comment: Any help to get it right is appreciated.

Comment: `Do you mean that I need to use Latitude instead of Longitude` sure, if you walk north or south only. Of course if you move east/west measuring latitude will show no change. As the little girl in some Mexican food product ad says ... why not use both?

Comment: @JaromandaX I know that one degree of Longitude is about 45 miles. I thought that moving forward/backward should change the Longitude value because I traveled some distance of those 45 miles. But, after thinking again, I think the digits after the decimal points are referring to the space after the whole degree to the next degree. Am I right? What I don't understand is, why the 2 or three digits on the right side change? And why does the value of Longitude would change if I'm moving west,east,north or south if I am still on the same Longitude?

Comment: `I know that one degree of Longitude is about 45 miles` that's at about 49N or 49S ... but say at 30N or 30S ... one degree of latitude is 60 miles. `And why does the value of Longitude would change if I'm moving west,east,north or south if I am still on the same Longitude?` firstly, the earth is a sphere, secondly if you move east or west, your longitude won't stay the same, because longitude measures how far east/west you are of the prime meridian - which, on this (spherical) earth is the line that runs N/S through greenwich england

Comment: Have a play with [this](https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gccalc.shtml) you'll see that your assumptions are all wrong

Comment: @JaromandaX I'd appreciate you telling me the facts.

Comment: ahh, I see the typo in my first comment ... that should've said `also, walking 10 metres will change longitude by a varying amount, depending on your latitude`, which is clearly inferable from your question